# What's "reviving"?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

Sometimes I see people lying on the ground, waiting to be "revived".

I can revive them all right, but this never happens to me.

Is it random, given by a Perk or something else that I've been missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to equip Second Chance Pro. For the opportunity to purchase the Pro variant you need to equip Second Chance and complete these three challenges.

- Kills – Get 10 kills while in Second Chance.
- Revenge – While in Second Chance, kill the enemy who downed you 5 times.
- Headshot – Get 1 headshot kill while in Second Chance.

The ability of your team mates to revive you does not depend on their perk setup. Second Chance Pro will also let you stay "downed" for longer.

Comment: It is based on the perk of the same name from Call of Duty World at War.  It will also help you spot noobs in black ops..:)

Comment: @Dark I don't think it's a noob perk. It takes quite a bit of skill to kill people with the (extremely horrible) pistols of Black Ops in the few extra seconds you get from second chance

Comment: @Earlz - IMO, it is a pretty annoying perk even it is does take some skill to shoot with the pistol.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Second Chance Pro, then when you go down and pull out your pistol, ANY OTHER PLAYER can come and 'revive' you.  Basically, it's like Gears of War, where when you 'die' your team mate has to get to you and help you back up so you can continue fighting.

Keep in mind that once you unlock Second Chance Pro, you still have to buy the perk in order to use it!

Comment: Are you sure that the reviving person has to have Second Chance too? Because, I can almost swear that I revived someone without having the Perk.

Comment: @Bora, you are right.  You don't need SC to revive.  Editing.